# How to properly concatenate Pandas Series if data split between time period?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

Indexing by Pandas Datetime, I am counting events by week and plotting them. Each object is currently a `pandas.core.series.Series`. Because the data is downloaded yearly, certain weeks are split. Here is an example:

```
Datetime
2005-12-18    1840
2005-12-25    1959
2006-01-01    1695

Datetime
2006-01-01     285
2006-01-08    1917
2006-01-15    1821
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

The week of `2006-01-01` should have `285 + 1695 = 1980` total events.

If I concatenate these two Series,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([weeks2005, weeks2006])
```

this does not happen. There will be large "spikes" in the data/plots due to these discontinuities. How can I amend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`:

```
print weeks2005.add(weeks2006, fill_value=0)
2005-12-18    1840
2005-12-25    1959
2006-01-01    1980
2006-01-08    1917
2006-01-15    1821
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: float64
```

And then you can cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print weeks2005.add(weeks2006, fill_value=0).astype(int)
2005-12-18    1840
2005-12-25    1959
2006-01-01    1980
2006-01-08    1917
2006-01-15    1821
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int32
```

EDIT:

If you have 50 `Series`, you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` with `sum`:

```
import pandas as pd

dt1 = pd.to_datetime('2005-12-18')
idx1 = pd.date_range(dt1, periods=3, freq='W-SUN')
weeks2005 = pd.Series( [1840, 1959, 1695], index=idx1)

dt2 = pd.to_datetime('2006-01-01')
idx2 = pd.date_range(dt2, periods=3, freq='W-SUN')
weeks2006 = pd.Series( [285, 1917, 1821], index=idx2)

dt3 = pd.to_datetime('2006-01-15')
idx3 = pd.date_range(dt3, periods=3, freq='W-SUN')
weeks2006a = pd.Series( [100, 200, 500], index=idx3)

weeks = [weeks2005, weeks2006, weeks2006a ] 
print weeks
[2005-12-18    1840
2005-12-25    1959
2006-01-01    1695
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64, 2006-01-01     285
2006-01-08    1917
2006-01-15    1821
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64, 2006-01-15    100
2006-01-22    200
2006-01-29    500
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64]
```

```
#concat list of series 
#duplicity of some index value in output series
concated_series = pd.concat([weeks2005, weeks2006, weeks2006a]
#concated_series = pd.concat(weeks)
print concated_series
#2005-12-18    1840
#2005-12-25    1959
#2006-01-01    1695
#2006-01-01     285
#2006-01-08    1917
#2006-01-15    1821
#2006-01-15     100
#2006-01-22     200
#2006-01-29     500
#dtype: int64

#grouping by index and aggregation sum
output = concated_series.groupby(by=concated_series.index).sum()
#level=0 is first level of multiindex, but it works in index too
#output = concated_series.groupby(level=0).sum()
print output

#2005-12-18    1840
#2005-12-25    1959
#2006-01-01    1980
#2006-01-08    1917
#2006-01-15    1921
#2006-01-22     200
#2006-01-29     500
#dtype: int64
```

More information about `groupby` with examples is [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/).

Comment: I think this would work for two `Series`. Unfortunately, I am working with something like 50....

Comment: `pd.concat(weeks).groupby(level=0).sum()` works like a charm! Ok, can you explain to me what you're doing? You first take the pandas series `week2005`, `week2006`, etc. and make a python list. Then you concatenate this python list, using `groupby(level=0).sum()`.

Comment: That is, explain to me `groupby(level=0).sum()`. Sorry, I rarely use pandas

Comment: I edit my answer with steps, thank you for accepting, you can upvote too. If you have some another questions, I will try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can trandform the series to dataframes and then merge them together using the date as key:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df2005 = pd.DataFrame(weeks2005.values)
df2005.columns = ["Datetime"]
df2006 = pd.DataFrame(weeks2006.values)
df2006.columns = ["Datetime"]

def split_datetime(record):
    record_splited = record.partition(" ")
    return record_splited[0]

def split_number(record):
    record_splited = record.partition(" ")
    return int(record_splited[1])

df2005["Number"] = df2005["Datetime"].apply(split_number)
df2005["Datetime"] = df2005["Datetime"].apply(split_datetime)

df2006["Number"] = df2006["Datetime"].apply(split_number)
df2006["Datetime"] = df2006["Datetime"].apply(split_datetime)

df_merge = pd.merge(df2005, df2006, on="Datetime", how="outer").fillna(0)
df_merge["Sum"] = df_merge["Number_x"] + df_merge["Number_y"]
df_merge.drop(["Number_x", "Number_y"], axis=1)

print df_merge
```

Comment: Why do you use `record_splited[2]` instead of `record_splited[1]`?

Comment: I read the data from csv and I didn't notice. You can use record_splited[1]. That is probably what you need for your data. I edited my answer.